# Move several commits from one branch to another?

Tags: git, rebase, cherry-pick

I started with branches `master` and `develop`. I made branch `foo` based off of `develop`. 7 commits later and now I realize I wish I made it off of `master`. I can cherry pick each commit, no big deal, but is there a slicker way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this.  You can leave off the `foo` if it's the currently checked-out branch.

```
git rebase --onto master develop foo
```

Comment: seems to have worked. could you explain the semantics? the git documentation for rebase is a bit hard to navigate as there are so many types of invocations…

Comment: @John, `develop` is the original branch point.  `--onto` specifies the new branch point.  If you don't specify `--onto` it will rebase you to the tip of the original branch point.  `foo` is the branch you want to rebase.  Essentially all the commits from `develop` onward are reapplied to the branch specified by `--onto`.

Comment: ah, so "rebase the diff of develop and foo onto master, and make that the new foo"